# PHP/JSON array problems when connecting to API

Tags: php, json

The below code is not rendering the line_items as a JSON array and I have searched/asked around to no avail.

Can anyone give me a hand here?

I've also included the json_encode data of the $orderShippingInfo variable.

Below is the JSON output:

```
{
"token":"API_KEY_HERE",
"email":"a.pinochet@chilehelicoptertours.com",
"line_items":{
   "sku":"12345",
   "name":"Product Name",
   "title":"Product Title",
   "price":"$1.99",
   "quantity":"1",
   "total_tax":"$0.00"
   },
"shipping_lines":{
   "title":"UPS",
   "price":"$0.00",
   "method":"UPS 3 DAY",
   "carrier":"UPS"
   },
"order_id":"0001",
"profile":"default",
"shipping_address":{
   "province":"AZ",
   "city":"Testville",
   "first_name":"Augusto",
   "last_name":"Pinochet",
   "zip":"12341",
   "province_code":"NY",
   "country":"US",
   "company":"Company Name, Inc.",
   "phone":"1112223333",
   "country_code":"US",
   "address1":"123 Testing Dr Street",
   "address2":"Suite #1"
   },
"subtotal_price":"$0.00",
"created_at":"2017-02-02",
"country_code":"US",
"total_discounts":"$0.00",
"total_price":"$0.00"
}
```

TIA!

```
<?php

$orderShippingInfo = array(
    'token' => 'API_KEY_HERE',
    'email' => 'a.pinochet@chilehelicoptertours.com',
    'line_items' => array(
        'sku'=>'12345',
        'name'=>'Product Name',
        'title'=>'Product Title',
        'price'=> '$1.99',
        'quantity' => '1',
        'total_tax' => '$0.00',
    ),
    'shipping_lines' => array(
        'title' => 'UPS',
        'price' => '$0.00',
        'method' => 'UPS 3 DAY',
        'carrier' => 'UPS',
    ),
    'order_id' => '0001',
    'profile' => 'default',
    'shipping_address' => array(
        'province' => 'AZ',
        'city' => 'Testville',
        'first_name' => 'Augusto',
        'last_name' => 'Pinochet',
        'zip' => '12341',
        'province_code' => 'NY',
        'country' => 'US',
        'company' => 'Company Name, Inc.',
        'phone' => '1112223333',
        'country_code' => 'US',
        'address1' => '123 Testing Dr Street',
        'address2' => 'Suite #1',
    ),
    'subtotal_price' => '$0.00',
    'created_at' => date('Y-m-d'),
    'country_code' => 'US',
    'total_discounts' => '$0.00',
    'total_price' => '$0.00',
);

echo json_encode($orderShippingInfo);

?>
```

Comment: `$orderShippingInfo = json_decode($json, true);`

Comment: @Mohammad He is ENCODING a PHP Array

Comment: so you want the line_items to remain an array rather than a json string?

Answer (score 2):

You need to make your array of line items an array of them.

For example:

```
$orderShippingInfo = array(
'token' => 'API_KEY_HERE',
'email' => 'a.pinochet@chilehelicoptertours.com',
'line_items' => array(
    array(
        'sku'=>'12345',
        'name'=>'Product Name',
        'title'=>'Product Title',
        'price'=> '$1.99',
        'quantity' => '1',
        'total_tax' => '$0.00',
    )
),
'shipping_lines' => array(
    'title' => 'UPS',
    'price' => '$0.00',
    'method' => 'UPS 3 DAY',
    'carrier' => 'UPS',
),
'order_id' => '0001',
'profile' => 'default',
'shipping_address' => array(
    'province' => 'AZ',
    'city' => 'Testville',
    'first_name' => 'Augusto',
    'last_name' => 'Pinochet',
    'zip' => '12341',
    'province_code' => 'NY',
    'country' => 'US',
    'company' => 'Company Name, Inc.',
    'phone' => '1112223333',
    'country_code' => 'US',
    'address1' => '123 Testing Dr Street',
    'address2' => 'Suite #1',
),
'subtotal_price' => '$0.00',
'created_at' => date('Y-m-d'),
'country_code' => 'US',
'total_discounts' => '$0.00',
'total_price' => '$0.00',
);
```

Then you can add a second line item to the array if you require.

Comment: The same may be true for your `shipping_lines` also

Answer (score 1):

The reason for this is that javascript does not have an associative array concept, so to produce one out of a `json_encode()` would break javascript.

See this example of what json_encode will do

```
$xx = ['a','b'];

$yy = ['one'=> 1, 'two'=>2];

print_r($xx);
echo json_encode($xx).PHP_EOL;
print_r($yy);
echo json_encode($yy);


Array
(
    [0] => a
    [1] => b
)
["a","b"]    // note this is a JSON array
Array
(
    [one] => 1
    [two] => 2
)
{"one":1,"two":2}  // note this is a JSON object
```

If the PHP array is numerically indexed, you get a JSON array

If the PHP array is assoc array it will create an JSON Object

If for some reason you specifically want a JSON String representation to be an array you could just add a `[]` to the `$orderShippingInfo[] = array(` like this

```
$orderShippingInfo[] = array(
'token' => 'API_KEY_HERE',
'email' => 'a.pinochet@chilehelicoptertours.com',
'line_items' => array(
    'sku'=>'12345',
    'name'=>'Product Name',
    'title'=>'Product Title',
    'price'=> '$1.99',
. . .
. . .
```

Comment: This is correct. JavaScript doesn't have associative arrays so it must convert the data into an object.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, I had forgotten the reason.